# Is hiding a member in the base class a bad smell in the code?

Tags: c#, .net, new-operator, member-hiding

To me, it sounds more like an exception to hide a member in the base class in order to hack something instead of refactoring a bad design...

Maybe I am wrong. But...

Is it a code smell to hide a member in the base class with 'new' keyword?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean. Could you give a code sample?

Comment: I am lil confused here, whats the use of making a member new in base class?? Because you can not have virtual and new in base class. Just virtual or new. If you have new in base class, you never can override it in derive class. So whats the use of the whole point?

Comment: As long as you're working inside the Liskov substitution principle there's no problem with this at all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the intent. If the purpose is to clarify the concrete return type, for example, then it might not be unreasonable. The classic example here is `DbConnection`. It is *useful* that `SqlConnection` re-declares `CreateCommand` etc, by returning `SqlCommand` rather than `DbCommand`, since `SqlCommand` has many platform-specific features that would otherwise be a pain. A key point, here, though is that the `DbConnection` method still works, and the purpose and meaning of the two methods is the same.

If you are doing this and the methods **do something different**, or **return something different**, then there are occasions it can cause confusion. And times it can still make sense ;p If they do the same thing, and only vary by formally stating something about the implementation *that is useful to the caller*, then fine.

Answer (score 0):

May be this can help.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/05/21/method-hiding-apologia.aspx